# Problem returning data from Search Query in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET Core MVC development. I'm trying to create a search query that returns the book if author name or the book title matches from a dummy database.

This is my `BookRepository` (data source):

```
public class BookRepository
{
        public List<BookModel> SearchBook(string title, string authorName)
        {
            return DataSource().Where(x => x.Title.Contains(title) || x.Author.Contains(authorName)).ToList();
        }

        private List<BookModel> DataSource()
        {
            return new List<BookModel>
            {
                new BookModel(){Id=1, Author="Einstein", Title="The Grand Design"},
                new BookModel(){Id=2, Author="Author", Title="ASP.Net"},
                new BookModel(){Id=3, Author="Author1", Title="Visual Studio"}
            };
        }
}
```

My `BookController` class is:

```
using Book_Store.Repository;

namespace Book_Store.Controllers
{
    public class BookController : Controller
    {
        private readonly BookRepository bookRepository = null;

        public BookController()
        {
            bookRepository = new BookRepository();
        }

        public List<BookModel> SearchBook(string bookName, string authorName)
        {
            return bookRepository.SearchBook(bookName, authorName);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this query is returning a null array every time. I'm executing the command like this:

[image: Query]

Can someone please identify the problem in this rather simple program?

Thanks!

Comment: In the search query you are passing in the author as the book name and the author as the book name.

Comment: Also the author and book name do not match the any of the records.

Comment: @ILally Oopps! I made the mistake while pasting the screenshot. I updated the image, please note that now bookName = "The Grand Design" and authorName = "Einstein" should match with Record 1 but the output is still null :(

Comment: @Mehak For some reason you have the quotes `"` in the URL for the variables. This means you have a string `"\"Einstein\""` as the author name, including the quotes. But the author of the book is named `Einstein`, not `"Einstein"`.

Comment: @Progman Thank you so much for pointing this out. Removing the quotes fixed the problem!!